# Error, Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a beginner in Java, when I compile the code below, I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Comparision {
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        Scanner j = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        System.out.println("enter the value for a");
        a = j.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the value for b");
        b = j.nextInt();
        if(a > b)
            System.out.println("a is greater");
        else
            System.out.println("b is greater");
    }
}
```

Comment: String should be `String` and not `string`

Comment: ohh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Thanks!

Comment: See that compiler must show you that string should be replaced by String.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Comparision {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner j=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        System.out.println("enter the value for a");
        a=j.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the value for b");
        b=j.nextInt();
        if(a>b)
        {
            System.out.println("a is greater");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("b is greater");
    }
}
```

String not string  // java classes start with Uppercase Letters

Answer (score 0):

java is a case sensitive languaje...

this

```
public static void main(string[] args)
```

is not the same as this...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

look exactly at the parameters...

and see that **String** is not the same as **string**...